# 'Account' does not contain a definition for 'Withdraw' and no accessible extension method 'Withdraw' error

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-code

Full error:

> 'Account' does not contain a definition for 'Withdraw' and no accessible extension method 'Withdraw' accepting a first argument of type 'Account' could be found

```
using System;

namespace Account
{
    class TestAccount
    {
        public string Name;
        public decimal Balance;

        public void Account(string Name, decimal Balance)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Balance = 100;

        }

        //Accessor
        public string getName()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        public string getBalance()
        {
            return this.Balance.ToString("C");;
        }
        //Mutators
        public void setName(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        public void setBalance(decimal Balance)
        {
            this.Balance = Balance;
        }
        //Methods

        public void Deposit(decimal amount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to deposit? Enter an amount: ");
            decimal AmountAdded = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Balance = amount + AmountAdded;
            amount = Balance;

            Console.WriteLine("You just added: " + amount.ToString("C"));
        }

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to Withdraw? Enter an amount: ");
            decimal AmountWithdraw = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Balance = amount - AmountWithdraw;
            amount = Balance;

            Console.WriteLine("You just Withdrew: " + amount.ToString("C"));
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The name of the account is " + Name + "Your Balance is: " + Balance.ToString("C"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main class

[image]

Comment: Yes, you've created an instance of `Account`. That doesn't have a `Withdraw` method. The `TestAccount` class does though. I would *strongly* recommend that you don't give your namespace the same name as your class, mind you.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest you learn about properties and .NET naming conventions - and avoiding public fields.